# vb.net loop through this month and past 6 months

Tags: vb.net, loops

I am trying loop though this month until past six months using vb.net and get the the month as integer and year only and pass this to my sql statement. but cannot seem to figure it out..

so far i got this :

```
        Dim dtNow As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim pastSixMonths As DateTime = dtNow.AddMonths(-6)

        For i As Integer = dtNow.Month To pastSixMonths.Month

        Next
```

can someone help please(no linq please)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to know how to loop month for month Quantum Leap?

```
Dim result As New List(Of String)
Dim currentDate = Now()
Dim last6Month = Now().AddMonths(-6)
While currentDate >= last6Month
    result.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", currentDate.Month, currentDate.Year))
    currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(-1)
End While

result.Clear()
' or the other way round :
currentDate = Now().AddMonths(-6)
While currentDate <= Now()
    result.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", currentDate.Month, currentDate.Year))
    currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(1)
End While
```

Comment: this will loop forever giving me m=2 and y=2012

Comment: @Sam1: I missed the assignement in the first place. Now it works as expected.

Comment: thanks for that, would it be possible to have the month and year in other way e.g. 9-2011, 10-2011, 11-2011, 12-2011, 1-2012, 2-2012 instead of 1-2012, 2-2012, 12-2011, 11-2011, 10-2011, 9-2011